# Is the -s here an abbreviation?

Tags: grammar

> I would like to promote mutual understanding between two peoples

Is the `-s` added on the word `people` a mistake or an abbreviation that can be interpreted as the following?

> I would like to promote mutual understanding between two country's people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't say **peoples** when you're referring to a bunch of people. That's a blatant mistake. The word **people** is already plural. The singular form of **people** is **person**. So, it's one person if we're talking about a single individual and it's people if we're talking about more than one individual.

However, you can say **peoples** in situations when you're talking about different ethnic groups. In this case, **a people** basically means a nation and **peoples** means more than one nation (*ethnic group* is a better definition though because the word *nation* is rather a political concept). So, it's neither a mistake nor an abbreviation. It's perfectly valid English grammar.

Example:

> The native **peoples** of Canada number more than 40 ethnic groups.

Comment: Your second paragraph is good (although I think you mean "ethnic" not "ethical"). However, your assertion that his example sentence contains a blatant mistake is completely incorrect! You would use "peoples" in that context precisely because you **were** speaking about the people of two different nations or groups. There is no mistake in it. In fact, if you said "between two people," you would mean **exactly** two persons.

Comment: Well, I didn't read it like that for some reason. I thought he was talking about two individuals. Context is kind. What else can I say?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I obviously got your reading at the end. I think the way the OP rewrote it with "two country's people" provides the needed context, though.

Comment: I thought he was talking about two country people. People who live in the country. You know what I mean? Probably, that **'s** threw me off. (and by the way, it should be **context is king**, not **context is kind**. Just a minor typo)

Comment: "The singular form of people is person." sorta, but not quite. person has a plural persons, but which is generally replaced with people (known as suppletion).

Comment: Right, you still can see **persons** used, mostly, in legal context (*persons under 18 are not allowed*, for example), but I just didn't want to make the answer too complicated.

Comment: The "peoples" in this instance is merely talking about two separate groups of people.